# mod_wsgi directory outside of DocumentRoot?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Should my wsgi directory be completely outside of www?

DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/

WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/wsgi/

Something like that, yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a DocumentRoot when using a `WSGIScriptAlias /`.

The answer to your actual question: it's probably best, yeah. I usually set the DocumentRoot to a 404 folder (folder with an index.html that shows a 404 page) and the WSGIScriptAlias to the actual script. Whether the 404 folder is actually useful? No idea, I've never seen it get hit. However, it's a good idea to keep them separated to avoid direct access to the contents of your code... which is something I have seen happen.

Comment: Jesus, SO commenting system is weird (tried to copy in a code snippet). So, (Alias /public/ /usr/local/server/www/), and (WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/server/wsgi/myapp.wsgi) should do the trick, even if I run it as a WSGIDaemonProcess?

Comment: Probably better than 404 document is a Directory block for directory which is default DocumentRoot, which contains 'Deny from All'. This will then throw back a forbidden page.